# datanucleus maven is throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: maven, jdo, datanucleus, isis

I'm trying to get starting using Apache Isis. I have created an sample project from the Isis maven archetype.

However when I do mvn clean install, I get the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:4.0.1:enhance (default) on project strategybuilder-dom: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer: InvocationTargetException: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:4.0.1:enhance (default) on project strategybuilder-dom: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.executeInJvm(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:348)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.enhance(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:281)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractEnhancerMojo.executeDataNucleusTool(AbstractEnhancerMojo.java:81)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.execute(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.datanucleus.maven.AbstractDataNucleusMojo.executeInJvm(AbstractDataNucleusMojo.java:331)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:439)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.jdo.JDOClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(JDOClassEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:730)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1281)
    ... 29 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have tried updating the datanucleus maven and core dependencies however the same error occurs.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get passed this?

Thanks

Comment: so you say you tried updating dependencies, but then don't actually mention WHAT versions you're using.

Comment: You certainly are NOT using DataNucleus v4.0+ since classes in that stack trace don't exist there ...

Comment: Apache Isis v1.8.0 uses DataNucleus 3.2.x, which uses ASM 3.x, which is not Java7 compatible.Apache Isis v1.9.0-SNAPSHOT uses DataNucleus 4.0.x which uses ASM 4.x, which is Java8 compatible.  

If you try to enhance an Apache 1.8.0 app with DataNuclues 4.0 enhancer then it won't work; is this your issue?